# testng - Abstractmethod error

Tags: java, testng, testng-eclipse

Im trying to create a testng class and run it in Eclipse but I get this below error -

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(Lorg/testng/ISuite;Lorg/testng/xml/XmlTest;Ljava/util/Collection;)Lorg/testng/TestRunner;
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:161)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:114)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1290)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1277)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1131)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:207)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:178)
```

My simple class

```
package test.selenium_project;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SampleNg {
  @Test
  public void f() {
      System.out.println("test");
  }
}
```

jar used

```
testng-6.5.1
```

Comment: Update your testng to the latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am expecting it is issue with testng jar. Can you please try once with eclipse-testng addin. [here](http://testng.org/doc/download.html) is the steps to install plug-in

[here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng/6.9.10) is the latest testng jar from maven repository..

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: Im not sure what is the issue. I created another project and its all working fine.